# Forwarding all HTTP/HTTPS traffic to a port with iptables

Tags: iptables, http, dhcp-server

I'm trying to setup a wireless network that routes all traffic to a local webserver (basically a hotel wifi login page).

Here's my dhcpd config:

```
$ cat /etc/dhcpd.conf
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
#   option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
    range 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.254;
}
```

And here is how I configure `iptables`:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1

iptables --flush
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain

iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
systemctl restart dhcpd4
```

Devices connected to my network are properly redirected to `192.168.1.1:80` if they try to connect to any IP address, but all requests to domain names end up timing out.

How do I get domain names to point to my local server as well (I commented out that line in my `dhcpd` config to see if that would help, but it didn't)? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you need DNS Server. It seems your network doesn't have any. Either dnsmasq or named will do. dnsmasq is easier to configure than named

Perhaps if you can elaborate your question further. Why do you want to redirect all domain names to a computer? If you want to filter them out, IP tables can filter them If you want to tcpdump them, https is encrypted.